# What key is used to generate an ARQC in Apple Pay?

Tags: applepay, emv

In the EMV protocol the IMK(ac) is used to generate the session key, which is used to generate an ARQC.  The IMK(ac) is exclusive to the chip and the card issuer host

As far as I understand, the card issuers do not share those keys with the card brand (i.e. Visa cannot validate your ARQC, only "The Bank of Peoria" who issued the card can).

**When an EMV Apple Pay transaction occurs in which the phone generates the ARQC, which IMK(ac) key is it using?**  Presumably it can't be the IMK(ac) from the original card, and thus the card issuer cannot validate the ARQC.

If it's an Apple IMK(ac) being used, then **does this mean that it is Apple validating that ARQC**?

If this is the case, what's the transaction flow that gives Apple the opportunity to validate the ARQC?

[Edited for clarity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile wallets like Apple/Google Pay don't use the card's PAN, so they don't need to provide the same ARQC that the card would have generated.

Instead, they use **network tokens** which are then mapped back to the **PAN** by the scheme.

##### Before the transaction

- the **Token Requestor** (e.g. Apple) sends its **IMKac** to the **Token Service Provider** (e.g. Visa) as part of the onboarding
- the **Device** (i.e. individual phone) is provisioned with a **Token** that can be mapped back to the PAN by the **Token Service Provider** as part of adding the card to Apple Pay

##### During the transaction

- the **Device**:

  - generates an ARQC, which it includes in the transaction
  - sends its **Token** in the place that the PAN would go
- the **Token Requestor**:

  - swaps out the **Token** for the **PAN**, which the issuer can recognise
  - validates the ARQC using the Token Requestor's IMKac, and forwards the result of this validation to the issuer

Answer (score 1):

Encryption will always use Session keys derived from an IMKac for Cryptogram generation. However the IMK need not be the same as what your physical card uses( you can manage this using a different CVN as host).
The same key will be available with the payment schemes(Visa, MasterCard etc.) who will validate the cryptogram during the transaction and send you the results of verification.

Wallet CVNs are different. If you as a card issuer host wants to verify the cryptogram, then you should have the IMKac for the CVN and your HSM should support the CVN. Ideally you can rely on the verification results code (in 44 for Visa and 48 SE71 for MC) to decide whether it can be approved or no.

In case if you have more documentations from Apple you can share, I would love to go through those :-) .

Comment: Many thanks - I've modified the question for clarity based on your answer.  Sadly, no, I have no documentation from Apple detailing the EMV version of Apple Pay.